# Iterate through list and handle not found items in Scala

Tags: scala

I have two lists A and B. I want to iterate through list B and find matches from A. For every non-match I would like to call another function to compute a new value.

I tried different ways to get to the wanted result:

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = List(1,2,4,5)
def compute(i:Int):Int = -1*i
// What I want: val r = List(1,2,-4,-5)
val r1 = b.foreach(bb => a.find(aa => aa==bb).getOrElse(compute(bb)))
val r2 = for {
 bb <- b
 r <- a.find(_ == bb).getOrElse(compute(bb))
} yield r
```

In reality my lists are some more complex, but this simple example works.

Obviously I'm missing something here and might even be attacking it the wrong way. I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: `r1` will return `Unit`, unless you use `map` instead of `foreach`. `r2` will not compute, (at least for `List[Int]`), since the RHS of the second row of your for-comprehension is not a collection (its an `Int`). You simply need to put this RHS in the yield, in which case it is the same as using `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe make a into set and then map.

```
val s = a.toSet
b.map{e => if (s.contains(e)) compute(e) else e}
```

Comment: The conversion to a `Set` is unnecessary; the `List` class has a `contains` function.

Comment: @chunjef The reason for conversion to `Set` is because its `contains` function is faster. So it doesn't matter if both lists are small, but it can significantly improve performance otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
val r = b map (elem => if (a contains elem) elem else compute(elem))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
b.map(i => {
  val matches = a.filter(x => x == i)
  if (matches.nonEmpty) matches.head
  else compute(i)
})
```

Comment: Why `filter` all the collection, once you know you found one matching value? `a.find(_ == i).getOrElse(compute(i))` gives exactly the same output, but avoid traversing `a` if the value is found before the end.